# If our monetary system (stocks, bonds, banks, etc.) suddenly collapsed, would humanity survive?

Tags: economy

Basically, would there be chaos?

Comment: While this is a really interesting question I think it's too broad "describe the world without money"... can you try to narrow it down? For example how would people acquire food? How would society ensure people didn't get more than their fair share of luxuries?

Comment: @Liath Hmmm...I suppose there would some sort of governmental checks and balances? The more work (or the more important your work is) you do, the more you receive.

Comment: Sounds sensible - I'm trying to guide you towards rephrasing your question so it can be answered in a sensible sized answer. As it stands it would take a huge amount of writing and speculation to respond http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: related for you to read ;) http://what-if.xkcd.com/118/

Comment: And also, while being from former Eastern Europe, I have to drop you also this link to read on: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communism

Comment: @PavelJanicek Oh, xkcd is funny.

Comment: I edited it @Liath.

Comment: To answer your edited question: Yes. And it already happened. Try to read articles about "The Great Depression"

Comment: Err. The question is now completely different from the original. Maybe figure out what exactly the question is first? (The old question was underdefined: would there be no state money, or a system that forbids money? The latter would be hard to define. To the new question, the answer is obviously yes. Humanity can recover from pretty destructive crises. But it too is underdefined, as it is unclear where exactly the monetary system "ends")

Comment: Errrr, never mind, I guess I'll delete this. This is way to broad and confusing.

Comment: @AryamanArora head into the Chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213 there's usually a few people in there more than happy to help you shape your question :) (sorry I'm not - I'm a little busy at the moment)

Comment: @AryamanArora even if you delete this now, feel free to come back and have another try at it later. We always love new questions.

Comment: @Liath While a good point in general, not really helpful in this specific case as [chat requires 20 rep.](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling ah, I hadn't realised that - meta? Where's the best place to direct people for additional help?

Comment: @Liath Unfortunately, [meta requires 5 rep](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta). For the completely new users, I'm not sure there is *any* good place other than using comments to try to flesh out the question, or encourage them to post good answers elsewhere. Getting two answer upvotes is sufficient for access to chat as well as [unlocking many other site features](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), and shouldn't be terribly hard to get. The purpose of the lower rep limits is mainly to keep out the worst spam.

Comment: I think most people should be able to find questions on this site that they are able to answer well enough to earn 2-3 upvotes on. Having reached that level, the original question can be revisited and for example a chat discussion be had about how to best phrase it to get the answers the OP seeks.

Comment: One thing that is completely implausible is a community *without* such systems - communities very, very quickly create new basic systems that then evolve afterwards, starting with barter economies but very rapidly including also debt, interest, collateral, etc. The question is not about transitioning from 'a system' to 'no system' but a chaotic transition between two different systems. There are real world history examples - hyperinflation (Weimar republic, some war economies, Zimbabwe, etc) and of isolated economic systems - e.g. gulag/prison situations.

Comment: one way to narrow the question could be to ask : in 2007-2008 what could have happened if the governments had not injected billions of Dollars/Euros to save the banking system ? I think it's OK since there is no economy SE.

Answer (score 7):

Yes; Our monetary system is simply a shortcut.

Say you have five chickens, and need a cow.

- *Without* money, you need to find someone who has a cow an needs five chickens.
- *With* money, you sell the chickens for \$100 and buy a cow for \$100.

You can still trade without money; it's just harder. An interesting side effect of this is that it's unlikely a CEO could ever be paid 2000x his employees wages, just because it would be near impossible to trade 10000 chickens for 2000 cows. Without getting into intricacies of taxation and rulership, compensation would be more or less proportional to work done and trade would be for items of equal value.

It would result in a near instantaneous redistribution of wealth.

That being said, it's very hard to operate without currency. What would likely happen is another form of currency quickly replaces it. For example, in the Fallout universe Bottle Caps are the currency, and "Pre-War Money" is more of a curio or antique. An issue could be that one regions currency is not accepted in another, but that happens even now.

Humanity would survive, but our civilization would halt or regress. Only about 10% of money is real, as our entire economy is built around the concept of fractional reserve banking. We would almost certainly go through a period of anarchy. With no money, there's no police, no jails, no mass transportation, no fuel, etc. Major cities would be bloody hell as factions competed for resources. A city the size of NYC or San Francisco can't sustain its population without importing thousands of tons of food and supplies.

Small towns and rural areas would be the least affected. Traditional Amish communities for example would see almost no difference.

Comment: You could have mentioned how credit works. Many "barter" societies simply work on credit. For your example, your cow gets you something else I can do for you, like help birthing your next calves or plowing that field.

Comment: From my experience with bartering, any credit is generally very short term (Drop off a cow, get chickens tomorrow), or effectively a money replacement. (like contributing to a pool of funds, where a cow is 1000barterbucks and a chicken is 200barterbucks)

Any examples?

Comment: You end up with a "gift economy," something we don't see very often in today's world. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_economy

Comment: "just because it would be near impossible to trade 10000 chickens for 2000 cows."  Bollocks, you haven't thought that through.  A CEO would get paid X (say instead of 1 cow a year, 2000 cows)... and would be able to make any trades he wants in whatever quantities he wants.